# How to call a function in a Google Spreadsheet from code in a Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet which has amongst other things, a function to create an invoice based on a specific job's data, createInvoice(jobNumber).

I would like to have a form in which I enter the Job Number and on Submit have it run createInvoice(jobNumber).

So the question is: What kind of coding is required to run createInvoice(jobNumber) from the form?

Thanks heaps in advance for any help with this.

Comment: The questions not massively clear here. Some Pseudocode for the workflow that you're looking for would help in a 1) Do X, 2) Do Y format.

I've attempted to answer your question below based on what I believe you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your options for running functions when the form is submitted is using an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Specifically, a [form submission trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers), either on [the form itself](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events), or on the [spreadsheet the data is written to](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).